# Threading in C# and library that does not work

Tags: c#, service, thread-safety, robotics

I am implementing a DSS service for a robot we are developing. I have already made an interface for the robot, which has some functions like connect, rotate, move etc. This interface is basically a wrapper around some functions that i got in a library, that does the controlling of the robot.

The whole thing works, as long as i dont have any asynchronous actions within my application. I can move the robot and whatnot and there are no issues. However when i try to implement this in my DSS service, it does not work. I can read whatever i want from the robot and it's outputs/inputs, but i am unable to move the robot itself, which makes me believe this is an issue with asynchronous operations, which makes some functions in the library unable to work.

I have looked around but i am unable to find any way or form in which i can get this done, because i would love to get my service running.

It hangs at the Robot.Move(move) statement, which is the one i am using from the library, making me believe that that is the function that is the culprit.

Comment: Can you show your asynchronous\threading code?

Comment: Could you confirm that by `DSS service` you mean [Distributed Software Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483067.aspx) rather than [Data Services Server](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dss/info) as the tag implies? Also, what robot and library are you using, some robotics libraries are inherently single threaded, so you have to make all calls from a single manager thread and let your application only talk through that manager.

Comment: Oh indeed it is Distributed Software Services, my bad. Also i have already found a fix to it by setting the Apartment State of the Thread in Single Thread Apartment.